# Scoring Profile Boosting negative with a boost below 1 in Azure Cognitive Search?

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-search, scoring-profile

Within Azure Cognitive Search scoring profiles, you can use boosting functions. Here is one I'm working with:

```
{
    "type": "magnitude",  
    "fieldName": "TasksCompleted",  
    "boost": .75,  
    "interpolation": "linear",  
    "magnitude": {
        "boostingRangeStart": 1,  
        "boostingRangeEnd": 30,  
        "constantBoostBeyondRange": true
}
```

I chose .75 for boost because I'm trying to have the boost be pretty small compared to some other boosts that are present. However, I noticed that the boost seemed to be working backwards, where 1 was the most boosted document and 30 was the least. This is opposite of how the other magnitude boosts were working.

Are scoring profile function boosts with a boost value below `1.0` reversed for some reason? Or do they somehow reduce the total boost for matching documents (even though my function aggregation is set to `SUM`)? I can't find any documentation around using numbers below 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Adding scoring profiles to a search index](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/index-add-scoring-profiles) this is documented for functions `freshness` property, but in general, using a boosting factor of less than `1` will reverse the boosting.